# Where is Blu-Ray on Linux

Tags: linux, media, blu-ray

I'm considering picking up a Blu-ray drive for a PC that will be used as my home entertainment center, but ideally, I'd like to keep a Linux based OS.

Are there currently any players in the Linux world able to decode and play Blu-ray (preferably with menus, but I know that took a while with DVDs, so it may be the same with Blu-ray).

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo! could help:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/BluRayAndHDDVD

Comment: I think he's looking for a software solution integrated with something similar to Boxee or XBMC. That guide alone makes it sound like it can be challenging to play many discs.

Comment: Will: It would be nice if Matt has provided this information.

Comment: Thanks Will, and furtelwart, you're right. I should have been more clear. Thanks.

Comment: Is your question answered? Do you need more information?

Answer (score 0):

I see this was asked in 2014, when there weren't really any options for Linux.
I'm a Blu-ray Disc Java hobby developer myself and have been missing an easy way of testing my creations on Ubuntu. So instead I've been using a Dune HD device in my network.

But we're writing 2018 now, and Linux is getting some options:

- [Kodi](http://www.kodi.tv) (from v18 which isn't out yet, but won't be long now).
- [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc)

I must admit I've never used Kodi before, but I think it is looking very promising. At the moment there are yet some bugs to be solved.

I've tested some of my own stuff with VLC for quite a while now, and at the moment VLC 3.0.1 seems decent.

It should be mentioned though, that I'm only using it for testing my own Blu-ray projects, and my own projects don't come with any Digital Rights Management hazzle as a Hollywood movie does. Someone else might have a comment on this.